# MySQL installation on Kamailio

Tags: mysql, database, installation, debian, kamailio

During installation of Kamailio SIP-server I run into the problem. After I Wrote `/usr/local/sbin/kamdbctl create` appears just `ERROR: database engine not specified, please setup one in the config script`. Know anyone possible reason?
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you take a look at the contents of the config script to see if a database engine was specified?

Answer (score 2):

Defining the DBENGINE in /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc resolved an issue with the same "error message" on Debian 8 Jessie.

Hope that helps!

//Fredrik

"""

Kamctlrc
The /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc is the configuration file for kamctl and kamdbctl. You need to edit it and set the SIP_DOMAIN to your SIP service domain (or IP address if you don't have a DNS hostname associated with your SIP service).

Set also the DBENGINE to be MYSQL and adjust other setting as you want.

"""

Answer (score 1):

Change MYLIBDIR  in kamdbctl to point to the path where the mysql file is available. That should allow it to find the right MySQL Engine.

One additional step i did prior was

apt-get install kamailio kamailio-mysql-modules

Answer (score 0):

I have done many changes in my /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc file to solve the problem but **ERROR: database engine not specified, please setup one in the config script** appears every time.
Then a simple thought that '#' is for comment solved the problem.

```
## database name (for ORACLE this is TNS name)
# DBNAME=MYSQL
```

Above was written in my /etc/kamailio/kamctlrc file and just removing the '#' created the database structure needed by Kamailio.

```
## database name (for ORACLE this is TNS name)
DBNAME=MYSQL
```

Just check that HASHTAG. ;)